# unable to connect the mysql database using shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

Am facing problem to connect the MySQL DB from shell script. Please find the below snippet i have written for connecting the MySQL data base. please suggest on this.

My shell Script:

```
      #!bin/bash
       Query="select * from Main"
       MySQL -u root -p '!!root!!' -e kpi << EOF
       $Query;
       EOF
```

Please check the above code and suggest me how to connect the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

`-pThePassword`

So you should delete the space between `-p` and the pass. Also you should not use an apostrophe (except it is part of the pass itself. Use a backslash to escape special characters.

Second: *nix systems are case sensitive, please try `mysql` instead of `MySQL`

**Update**

You could also try to type your password into a file and read it with your script

```
mysql -u root -p`cat /tmp/pass` -e "SHOW DATABASES"
```

The file `/tmp/pass` should contain your password without any newline char at the end.

**Update 2**

Your Script is wrong.

1. You can either use `mysql ... -e SELECT * FROM TABLE` or `mysql ... << EOF` (without -e). You should not mix them.
2. Don't forget to pass the databasename as a parameter (or with `use databasename;`) in the sql
3. Don't forget to add a `;` after every sql command, if you have multiple statements

Method One:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword databasename -e "SELECT * FROM main"
```

Method Two:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword databasename << EOF
SELECT * FROM main
EOF
```

Method Three:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword << EOF
USE databasename;
SELECT * FROM main;
EOF
```

Comment: tried. but still am getting the error as "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: What happens if you just use `mysql -u root -p` without giving a pass? MySQL will prompt you to enter the password. Does this work?

Comment: @sivakumar That means your password is incorrect. Try another user. If you have forgotton and need to reset the password, maybe this helps: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Now I can able to connect the my sql database. after connecting the database am getting the below message:                           mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.30, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?..like this am getting. Please suggest on this.

Comment: @sivakumarV - Ok after you can connect you have to fix your code. I updated my answer.

Comment: Tried as you suggested, but again am getting access denied. But the same credentials i can able to login to the mysql directly. if i tried to login using shell script am getting error as access denied.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql --user=root --password=xxxxxx  -e "source dbscript.sql"
```

This should work for Windows and Linux.

If the password content contains a `!` (Exclamation mark) you should add a `\` (backslash) in front of it.